# Does Python SpeechRecognition work with WebRTC as AudioSource?

Tags: python, webrtc, speech-recognition, django-channels

I need to implement continuous real-time speech to text that can use WebRTC as an audio source. I would love to use the `speech_recognition` library ([here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition)) because it has this wonderful `.listen()` method that works perfectly as a VAD and also makes it easy to create a wav file later to feed it to my STT model of choice. In short, I would like to structure it like this (credits to [Ashutosh Dongare](https://github.com/AshutoshDongare)):

```
audio_input_file = "micAudioInput.wav"  
audio_output_file = "ttsAudioOutput.wav"

while True:

    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as SR_AudioSource:
            print("Say something...")
            mic_audio = r_audio.listen(SR_AudioSource,1,4) # timeout=1, phrase_time_limit=4

    except: #This is required if there is no Audio input or some error
        print("Found not capture mic input or no audio...")
        continue #continue next mic input loop if there was any error

    with open(audio_input_file, "wb") as file:
        file.write(mic_audio.get_wav_data())
        file.flush()
        file.close()

    # Check if there is input audio file saved otherwise continue listening 
    if not os.path.exists(audio_input_file):
        print("no input file exists")
        continue

    # Read audio file into batches and create input pipelie for STT
    batches = split_into_batches(glob(audio_input_file), batch_size=10)
    readbatchout = read_batch(batches[0])
    input = prepare_model_input(read_batch(batches[0]), device=device)

    #feed to STT model and get the text output
    output = stt_model(input)
    you_said = decoder(output[0].cpu())
    print(you_said)

    if(you_said == ""):
        print("No speech recognized...")
        continue
    
    #check if user wants to stop
    if(re.search("exit",you_said) or re.search("stop",you_said) or re.search("quit",you_said)):
        break
```

It works perfectly using a physical microphone locally. The only issue is that I am pretty sure that `speech_recognition` only accepts microphones of the device it is run on as an `AudioSource` (and I know that [PyAudio only works that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62376762/16457729)) as the [documentation states](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#microphonedevice_index-unionint-none--none-sample_rate-int--16000-chunk_size-int--1024---microphone) that the `Microphone` class

> [c]reates a new Microphone instance, which represents a physical
> microphone on the computer.

Does this mean it is not possible to use it with WebRTC as source? And if not, what would be a good substitute to its `.listen()`? Also: Is this concept of an infinite loop generally even feasible in the browser or is it a bad idea? I plan on implementing this in Django and handling the WebSocket
server with Django Channels.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a late answer in case someone stumble upon this answer. Yes, SpeechRecognition can work with WebRTC as AudioSource.

Here's how I did it:

- Implement a custom `MediaStreamTrack` from [aiortc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc)

  - The custom `MediaStreamTrack` has a custom `AudioSource` member from SpeechRecognition
  - On recv, it resamples to the [AudioFrame](https://pyav.org/docs/stable/api/audio.html#av.audio.frame.AudioFrame) and write the frame to a [AudioFifo](https://pyav.org/docs/stable/api/audio.html#av.audio.fifo.AudioFifo) present in the custom `AudioSource`
- The custom `AudioSource` is just a passthrough for the Fifo, adding a bit of logic

First here's the code for the custom `MediaStreamTrack` inspired from [the VideoTransformTrack example of aiortc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/f0126eb7e8fcf449f75e78294111317bf299f12c/examples/server/server.py#L22-L89):

```py
class AudioTransformTrack(MediaStreamTrack):
    kind = "audio"

    def __init__(self, track):
        super().__init__()
        self.track = track
        rate = 16_000  # Whisper has a sample rate of 16000
        audio_format = 's16p'
        sample_width = av.AudioFormat(audio_format).bytes
        self.resampler = av.AudioResampler(format=audio_format, layout='mono', rate=rate)
        self.source = WebRTCSource(sample_rate=rate, sample_width=sample_width)

    async def recv(self):
        out_frame: av.AudioFrame = await self.track.recv()

        out_frames = self.resampler.resample(out_frame)

        for frame in out_frames:
            self.source.stream.write(frame)

        return out_frame
```

Next the implementation of the custom AudioSource, inspired by the Microphone class:

```py
class WebRTCSource(AudioSource):
    def __init__(self, sample_rate=None, chunk_size=1024, sample_width=4):
        # Those are the only 4 properties required by the recognizer.listen method
        self.stream = WebRTCSource.MicrophoneStream()
        self.SAMPLE_RATE = sample_rate  # sampling rate in Hertz
        self.CHUNK = chunk_size  # number of frames stored in each buffer
        self.SAMPLE_WIDTH = sample_width  # size of each sample

    class MicrophoneStream(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.stream = av.AudioFifo()
            self.event = threading.Event()

        def write(self, frame: av.AudioFrame):
            assert type(frame) is av.AudioFrame, "Tried to write something that is not AudioFrame"
            self.stream.write(frame=frame)
            self.event.set()

        def read(self, size) -> bytes:
            frames: av.AudioFrame = self.stream.read(size)

            # while no frame, wait until some is written using an event
            while frames is None:
                self.event.wait()
                self.event.clear()
                frames = self.stream.read(size)

            # convert the frame to bytes
            data: np.ndarray = frames.to_ndarray()
            return data.tobytes()
```

When listening to the source, make sure you do this asynchronously. In my case, I start a new thread for the listening.

```py
def listen(source: AudioSource):
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

    while True:
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
        # do something with the audio...

# on webrtc receive track:
t = AudioTransformTrack(relay.subscribe(track))
thread = threading.Thread(target=listen, args=(t.source,))
thread.start()
```